# Compilation of FromInt.v failing on MacOS (trying to use wp plugin with Coq)

Tags: frama-c, why3

If I try:

```
frama-c -val -wp -wp-rte -wp-prover coq acsl-case-study.c
```

then I get the following error:

```
File "/var/folders/m5/pq77jvw12md76t51_6t51vfwhptwwy/T/wp7149b4.dir/coqwp/real/FromInt.v", line 22, characters 15-32:
Error: The reference Reals.Raxioms.IZR was not found in the current
environment.
```

(all other files before FromInt.v seem to compile successfully).  This behaviour persists even after uninstalling and reinstalling why3 and frama-c packages via opam.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

I'm using MacOS High Sierra.  Relevant version info: Why3 platform, version 0.88.3, OCaml toplevel, version 4.05.0, Frama-C Phosphorus-20170501c02v53d5hv2r, and Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.7.0 (December 2017), all installed through opam.

Comment: Indeed, both Phosphorus and Sulfur (the current version of Frama-C) are incompatible with Coq >= 8.7.0. Support for newer Coq (and Why3) is in progress and should be available for Chlorine.

Comment: @Virgile, thanks for the information.  When is Chlorine due to be released?

Comment: We try to have 2 release per year, so Chlorine could be expected by the end of May. But of course, a SO comment cannot be considered as an official statement in this respect .

Comment: As a side note, if you do not depend on Coq 8.7 for other purposes, you can pin it to 8.6 (`opam pin add coq 8.6`). This should get you a version compatible with Sulfur (not tested, though).

Comment: @Virgile, I'm not using Coq for anything else, no.  I can revert back to 8.6 in that case.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the Frama-C opam packages have been updated to incorporate the extra Coq constraint, so this error should not happen anymore (opam should dutifully report the incompatibility with Coq 8.7 before letting the user try to compile Frama-C).